# Binary Tree Generic Problemm

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree

Currently studying for an exam, and I stuck at Generic Binary Tree

```
public interface BinaryTreeNode <T>{

    public void setParent(T binaryTreeNodeImpl);
    public void setLeft(T left);

    public void setRight(T right);
    public T getRoot() ;
    public T getParent();
    public void setValue(T string);
    public T getLeft();


}
```

İt is my interface.

```
public class BinaryTreeNodeImpl <T> implements  BinaryTreeNode <T>{

    public T value;
    private T Root;
    private T right;
    private T parent;
    private T left;




    public void  setRight(T right) {
        this.right = right;
         ( (BinaryTreeNode<T>) right).setParent( (T) this);


    }
     public T getRoot() { 
         return  (T) Root; 
    }
      public void setValue(T value) {
          this.value=value;

      }
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public T getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(T binaryTreeNodeImpl) {
        parent= binaryTreeNodeImpl;

    }
    public T getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public T getLeft() {
        return left;
    }


    public void setLeft(T left) {
        this.left =  left;
        (  (BinaryTreeNode<T>) left).setParent((T) this);
    }


}
```

it is my Binary Tree Implement .When I try to run. Bellow code I've got Value method is undefined for String.

```
BinaryTreeNode<String> root = new BinaryTreeNodeImpl<String>();
        root.setValue("abc");
        BinaryTreeNode<String> left = new BinaryTreeNodeImpl<String>();
        left.setValue("xyz");
        root.setLeft(left);
        System.out.println(left.getParent().getValue());
        System.out.println(root.getLeft().getValue());
```

I did not understand where I did wrong ? Should I create abstract method for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you had the error is that `getParent()` and `getLeft()` return `T`, which is `String`, when you meant to return a node here.

Your references to root, parent, left, and right in your `BinaryTreeNode` interface have type `T`, but that is the type of data that the node needs to reference, not the node itself.  Change the datatype of the return values and parameters of the methods that don't have anything to do with the value from `T` to `BinaryTreeNode<T>`.  This will of course affect the same declarations in your implementing class `BinaryTreeNodeImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getParent()` has a return type `T`; I am under the impression that you want this to be `BinaryTreeNode<T>` since a parent of a `BinaryTreeNode` should be a binary tree node (preferably of the same type).

Your current design is akin to saying that the parent of a `BinaryTreeNode` can be a `String` or an `Integer` or a cat and you are calling the `getValue()` on that, which obviously is not defined, hence the error.

Make the same edits to the return types in the method declarations in your interface.